# How do I Increase the Size of the card when the text area overflows , so that the submit button is visible all the Time

Tags: html, css, reactjs

React Component : -  This is the react component that has the form in this form i have text area which has a fixed width of 100%

```
import React from 'react'
import '../../Components/utilities.css'
import './Form.css'

export default function Form() {
  return (
    <div className='container-form card'>
        <h2>Request a Demo</h2>
                <form action="https://formsubmit.co/ccf63a53d8e3631e23be6f390b5c9d9d" method="POST" name="contact" >
                    
                    <input type="text" name="_honey" style={{display:'none'}}/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html"/>

                    <div className="form-control">
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-control">
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required id="email"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-control">
                        <input type="tel" name="number" placeholder="Mobile Number" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-control">
                        <input type="text" name="country code" placeholder="Country Code" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-control">
                        <input type="text" name="tenative budget" placeholder="Tenative Budget" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-control">
                        <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company Name" required/>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <div className="form-control">
                        
                        <textarea type='text' name="" className="description" 
                                    placeholder='Please explain what kind of web application do you want to build.'
                                    />

                    </div>
                    
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" className="btn btn-primary" ></input>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

It's CSS:-

```
.container-form{
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
    right: -60rem;
    height: 600px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 40px;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container-form h2{
    font-size: 300;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: auto;
}

.container-form .form-control {
    margin: 30px 0;
}

.container-form input[type="text"],
.container-form input[type="email"],
.container-form input[type="tel"]
{
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b3cb;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.container-form textarea[type='text']{
    border: 1px solid #b4b3cb;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 8rem;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    
    
}

.container-form input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Utility CSS:-

```
 
:root{
    --text: #010304;
    --background: #eaf3fa;
    --primary: #2b73b6;
    --secondary: #d6e6f5;
    --accent: #3082cf;
    --white: #fff;
}
/* Utilities */

.container{
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.container-form{
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.card{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: var(--primary);
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.btn-block{
    width: 40%;

    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: var(--primary);
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;

}
.btn-outline{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px #fff solid ;
}

.btn:hover{
    transform: scale(0.98);
}
/* Backgrounds & colored buttons */
.bg-primary, .btn-primary{
    background-color: var(--primary);
    color: #fff;
}
.bg-secondary, .btn-secondary{
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    color: #fff;
}
.bg-dark, .btn-dark{
    background-color: var(--dark-color);
    color: #fff;
}

.bg-light, .btn-light{
    background-color: var(--light-color);
    color: #333;
}

.bg-primary a, .btn-primary a,
.bg-secondary a, .btn-secondary a,
.bg-dark a, .btn-dark a{
    color: #fff;
}

/* Text colors */

.text-primary{
    color: var(--primary-color);
    
}
.text-secondary{
    color: var(--secondary-color);
    
}
.text-dark{
    color: var(--dark-color);
    
}

.text-light{
    color: var(--light-color);
    
}

/* Text Sizes */
 
.lead{
    font-size: 20px;
}


.sm{
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.md{
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.mdl{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.lg{
    font-size: 3rem;
}

.xl{
    font-size: 4rem;
}

.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}


/* font weights */

.bw{
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Alert */

.alert{
    background-color: var(--light-color);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    /* font-weight: bold; */
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.alert i{
    margin-right: 10px;

}

.alert-success{
    background-color: var(--success-color);
    color: #fff;
    
}

.alert-error{
    background-color: var(--error-color);
    color: #fff;

}

.alert-attention{
    background-color: var(--dark-color);
    color: #fff;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;    
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.grid-3{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
.grid-4{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

/* Margin */
.my-1{
    margin: 1rem 0;
}
.my-2{
    margin: 1.5rem 0;
}
.my-3{
    margin: 2rem 0;
}
.my-4{
    margin: 3rem 0;
}
.my-5{
    margin: 4rem 0;
}

.mx-1{
    margin: 0 1rem;
}
.mx-2{
    margin: 0 2rem;
}


.m-1{
    margin: 1rem;
}
.m-2{
    margin: 1.5rem;
}
.m-3{
    margin: 2rem;
}
.m-4{
    margin: 3rem;
}
.m-5{
    margin: 4rem;
}




/* Padding*/
.py-1{
    padding: 1rem 0;
}
.py-2{
    padding: 1.5rem 0;
}
.py-3{
    padding: 2rem 0;
}
.py-4{
    padding: 3rem 0;
}
.py-5{
    padding: 4rem 0;
}

.p-1{
    padding: 1rem;
}
.p-2{
    padding: 1.5rem;
}
.p-3{
    padding: 2rem;
}
.p-4{
    padding: 3rem;
}
.p-5{
    padding: 4rem;
}

.pb{
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

I tried to use overflow but it added a scroll bar. I want to make the card increase its length when ever the text area element increases in height and overflows.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider removing the `height` declaration in the `.container-form` rule and instead apply an equivalent `min-height` declaration instead:

```js
function Form() {
  return (
    <div className='container-form card'>
      <h2>Request a Demo</h2>
      <form action="https://formsubmit.co/ccf63a53d8e3631e23be6f390b5c9d9d" method="POST" name="contact" >

        <input type="text" name="_honey" style={{display:'none'}}/>
        <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html"/>

        <div className="form-control">
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-control">
          <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required id="email"/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-control">
          <input type="tel" name="number" placeholder="Mobile Number" required/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-control">
          <input type="text" name="country code" placeholder="Country Code" required/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-control">
          <input type="text" name="tenative budget" placeholder="Tenative Budget" required/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-control">
          <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company Name" required/>
        </div>

        <div className="form-control">
          <textarea type='text' name="" className="description" 
            placeholder='Please explain what kind of web application do you want to build.'
          />
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Send" className="btn btn-primary" ></input>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<Form/>);
```

```css
.container-form{
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
    right: -60rem;
    min-height: 600px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 40px;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container-form h2{
    font-size: 300;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: auto;
}

.container-form .form-control {
    margin: 30px 0;
}

.container-form input[type="text"],
.container-form input[type="email"],
.container-form input[type="tel"]
{
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b3cb;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.container-form textarea[type='text']{
    border: 1px solid #b4b3cb;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 8rem;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    
    
}

.container-form input:focus {
    outline: none;
}

 
:root{
    --text: #010304;
    --background: #eaf3fa;
    --primary: #2b73b6;
    --secondary: #d6e6f5;
    --accent: #3082cf;
    --white: #fff;
}
/* Utilities */

.container{
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.container-form{
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.card{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: var(--primary);
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.btn-block{
    width: 40%;

    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: var(--primary);
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;

}
.btn-outline{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px #fff solid ;
}

.btn:hover{
    transform: scale(0.98);
}
/* Backgrounds & colored buttons */
.bg-primary, .btn-primary{
    background-color: var(--primary);
    color: #fff;
}
.bg-secondary, .btn-secondary{
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    color: #fff;
}
.bg-dark, .btn-dark{
    background-color: var(--dark-color);
    color: #fff;
}

.bg-light, .btn-light{
    background-color: var(--light-color);
    color: #333;
}

.bg-primary a, .btn-primary a,
.bg-secondary a, .btn-secondary a,
.bg-dark a, .btn-dark a{
    color: #fff;
}

/* Text colors */

.text-primary{
    color: var(--primary-color);
    
}
.text-secondary{
    color: var(--secondary-color);
    
}
.text-dark{
    color: var(--dark-color);
    
}

.text-light{
    color: var(--light-color);
    
}

/* Text Sizes */
 
.lead{
    font-size: 20px;
}


.sm{
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.md{
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.mdl{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.lg{
    font-size: 3rem;
}

.xl{
    font-size: 4rem;
}

.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}


/* font weights */

.bw{
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Alert */

.alert{
    background-color: var(--light-color);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    /* font-weight: bold; */
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.alert i{
    margin-right: 10px;

}

.alert-success{
    background-color: var(--success-color);
    color: #fff;
    
}

.alert-error{
    background-color: var(--error-color);
    color: #fff;

}

.alert-attention{
    background-color: var(--dark-color);
    color: #fff;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;    
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.grid-3{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
.grid-4{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

/* Margin */
.my-1{
    margin: 1rem 0;
}
.my-2{
    margin: 1.5rem 0;
}
.my-3{
    margin: 2rem 0;
}
.my-4{
    margin: 3rem 0;
}
.my-5{
    margin: 4rem 0;
}

.mx-1{
    margin: 0 1rem;
}
.mx-2{
    margin: 0 2rem;
}


.m-1{
    margin: 1rem;
}
.m-2{
    margin: 1.5rem;
}
.m-3{
    margin: 2rem;
}
.m-4{
    margin: 3rem;
}
.m-5{
    margin: 4rem;
}




/* Padding*/
.py-1{
    padding: 1rem 0;
}
.py-2{
    padding: 1.5rem 0;
}
.py-3{
    padding: 2rem 0;
}
.py-4{
    padding: 3rem 0;
}
.py-5{
    padding: 4rem 0;
}

.p-1{
    padding: 1rem;
}
.p-2{
    padding: 1.5rem;
}
.p-3{
    padding: 2rem;
}
.p-4{
    padding: 3rem;
}
.p-5{
    padding: 4rem;
}

.pb{
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```